# How to delete a jsonb item in a nested psql array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table users:

```
`CREATE TABLE users(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username TEXT UNIQUE,
    saved_articles JSONB[],
  )`
```

I added a user like so:

```
      "INSERT INTO users (username, saved_articles) VALUES (?, array[]::jsonb[]) RETURNING id, username, saved_articles"
```

After adding some articles I have this data shape:

```
{ id: 1,
  username: 'test',
  saved_articles:
   [ { url: 'test',
       title: '',
       author: '',
       source: '',
       content:"",
       urlToImage: '' 
     },
     { url: 'not-test',
       title: '',
       author: '',
       source: '',
       content:"",
       urlToImage: '' 
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to be able to delete a specific item from the saved_articles array based on the url value.

For example, if my url value is 'test', after running the query my data should look like:

```
{ id: 1,
  username: 'test',
  saved_articles:
   [ { url: 'not-test',
       title: '',
       author: '',
       source: '',
       content:"",
       urlToImage: '' 
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your example data is not valid JSONB[].   Nor valid JSON for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the format of `JSONB` columns's value should be fixed. That might be tested through `CAST`ing `AS JSONB` by a `SELECT` statement such as

```
SELECT '{ "id": "1",
  "username": "test",
  "saved_articles":
   [ { "url": "test",
       "title": "",
       "author": "",
       "source": "",
       "content":"",
       "urlToImage": "" 
     },
     { "url": "not-test",
       "title": "",
       "author": "",
       "source": "",
       "content":"",
       "urlToImage": "" 
     }
   ]}'::jsonb
```

whether returns error or not.

Then, remove the desired element from the array by use of `jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'saved_articles')` function together with `->> 'url' != 'test'` criteria.

And then reconstruct the array by remaining elements by using `jsonb_build_array` and `jsonb_object_agg`.

At the last step concatenate the part which doesn't contain that individual array extracted by `json_data #- '{saved_articles}'` :

```
SELECT js0||jsonb_object_agg( 'saved_articles', js1 ) AS "Result JSONB"
  FROM
  (
   SELECT json_data #- '{saved_articles}' AS js0, jsonb_build_array( js ) AS js1
     FROM tab
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(json_data -> 'saved_articles') js
    WHERE js ->> 'url' != 'test'
   ) q
 GROUP BY js0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e222177cc8fef52def8bfcc02cc1b2ea)</kbd>